# How do I create a dynamic vacation countdown for my Excel calendar?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, calendar, countdown

So I have this Excel calendar that I've made that I use at work to track various things, and now I would like to add a "vacation countdown", that would display the remaining days until the next vacation, to it. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neweJ.png) is an image of a very simplified version with only the parts of the calendar that are relevant to this issue, and below the same in Table Markdown format.

| Date | Notes | Today is | =TODAY() |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15.8.2023 | vacation | Days until the next vacation | =DAYS((XLOOKUP("vacation";C4:C64;B4:B64));TODAY()) |
| 16.8.2023 | vacation |  |  |
| ... |  |  |  |
| 28.8.2023 | vacation |  |  |
| 29.8.2023 | vacation |  |  |

As can be seen from the image and the table I've tried to create the "vacation countdown" using the DAYS, XLOOKUP, and TODAY functions, and that worked fine until the value of TODAY > the date of the very first vacation day (i.e. the first vacation day is in the future, and not the past).

Now I could "resolve" the issue by manually entering the new ranges for the functions every time a vacation has passed, but that's not fun (nor a desirable solution). What I'm looking for is way to get the countdown to show only positive values (i.e. a countdown to only the upcoming vacation and not the ones in the past).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another alternative approach , using <kbd>TOCOL( )</kbd> needs **`MS365`** :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F3</kbd>

```
=DAYS(@TOCOL(IFS((C4:C36="vacation")*(B4:B36>F2),B4:B36),3),F2)
```

---

Another two cents from **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir, solution proposed is relatively simple and short.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F4</kbd>

```
=LET(x,FILTER(B4:B36,C4:C36<>""),XLOOKUP(F2,x,x,,1)-F2)
```

---

Comment: Nice. My two cents: `=LET(x,FILTER(B4:B36,C4:C36<>""),XLOOKUP(F2,x,x,,1)-F2)`

Comment: @JvdV Sir, gotcha, even i would have used the regular subtraction. Just tried to keep it same as OP, posted, let me update yours as well.

Comment: @JvdV Yes that works too, I just had to modify it a bit: `=LET(x,FILTER(B4:B36,C4:C36="vacation"),XLOOKUP(TODAY(),x,x,,1)-TODAY())` since I might have other notes in the "notes" column apart from "vacation". Great answers from all of you though, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

`=DAYS(TAKE(FILTER(B4:B64,(C4:C64="vacation")*(B4:B64>TODAY())),1),TODAY())`

It filters for all future dates with vacation-note and then takes the first result.

[image]